# Convert String to HTML Inputs and create string with binded value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, string

I want to generate a string with HTML inputs values (entered by the user).

My HTML Code for display a string with HTML inputs.

```
<div id="wid-12" ng-bind-html="finalString" compile-template></div>
```

JavaScript Code for convert string with HTML inputs.

```
        function convertStringToInputs() {
            var string = "Hi,Cricket match with !!!TEXT!!! on !!!DATE!!! Umpire is !!!TEXT!!! and price is !!!NUMBER!!! items.";
            var mapObj = {
                '!!!TEXT!!!': "<input type='text' placeholder='Enter text' ng-model='text'/>",
                '!!!DATE!!!': '<input type="date" placeholder="Enter date" ng-model="date"/>',
                '!!!NUMBER!!!': '<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number" ng-model="number"/>'
            };
            string = string.replace(/!!!TEXT!!!|!!!DATE!!!|!!!NUMBER!!!/gi, function (matched,key) {
                return mapObj[matched];
            });
            $scope.finalString = $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
        }
        convertStringToInputs();
```

This will display output like below.
[image]

Now if we enter data in inputs then it will display as below, but the problem is when we enter a value in one textbox it will also fill another textbox.[image]

After inserting all values if we click on save button then I want to make a string like below.

> Hi,Cricket match with Aus on 20-Dec-2017 Umpire is Aus and price is
>   120000  items.

JavaScript Code for save button

```
        function saveClick() {
            var a = $sce.getTrustedHtml($scope.finalString);
        }
```

Finally, I have listed what problems I face

1. it duplicates the same value in textbox if I enter a value in other textboxes.
2. Not able to generate string after input all inputs values (I have mentioned upper side).

Comment: Can you use Template Literals https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals ? Then this whole script becomes trivial.

Comment: Can you explain in more details??

Answer (score 0):

Too long to post in a comment. What I wanted to know is if you can use template literals, since they allow you to populate a string with the values of variables inside your code. No more messing around with manual string replacement:

```
var match = {
    "match_date" : "2018-01-01T16:30:00.000Z",
    "match_opponent" : "John Doe",
    "match_price" : "$13",
    "match_umpire" : "JaneDoe"
};

var template = `Hi,Cricket match with <input type='text' placeholder='Enter text' value="${match.match_opponent}" ng-model='text'/> on <input type="date" placeholder="Enter date" value="${match.match_date}" ng-model="date"/>Umpire is <input type='text' placeholder='Enter text' value="${match.match_umpire}" ng-model='text'/> and price is <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number" value="${match.match_price}" ng-model="number"/> items.`

return template;
```

Then you can just link the match values to your controller scope and seperate the models from input type or just remove them altogether.

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply. My inputs are not fixed if user wants more inputs in string then he can add more.i provided string is for example but in actual string is dynamic.